# Argument-dependent Name Lookup: add extra namespace to look into

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I would like to exploit the ADL rules to check for the function in an extra namespace:

Say we have a `class X`.

```
class X
 {
 ...
 };
```

In A call

```
X x;
f(x);
```

I'd like the compiler to look into `namespace funky`, that is until now unrelated to `class X`. But I don't want to clutter the coded by putting `funky::f` whenever calling `f`.

One way to achieve this is to define `class X` as a template class with an argument coming from `namespace funky`.

```
template <typename Fake = funky::someClassFromFunky>
class X
 {
 ...
 };
```

For a call `f(x)`, now, the compiler will indeed look for `funky::f`.

Is there a cleaner / simpler way of achieving the same behavior? (In particular, referring to some arbitrary class `someClassFromFunky` in the declaration of `class X` is awkward.)

Answer (score 3):

You can import f into your namespace like this:

```
using funky::f;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The key thing to note is you can do it so that it at the point of call, not just globally.

Comment: My problem is that I have a considerable number of functions from funky, operating on class X, that I would like to use (not just f, but say ~ 15 different functions).

Putting a using statement for each of those functions would be pretty annoying.

Comment: @MattHurst: I would suggest doing a using declaration for each one, putting them all together.  This way if you are searching for the function name, it is easy to spot that it is being imported from another namespace.

Comment: Also, such using statements would cause a different behavior. With `using`, the compiler would also consider `funky::f` for a call `int y; f(y);`.

Comment: @Matt: However, if `X` is in it's own namespace, and you put the `using` into that namespace, then it's only considered when you call `f(X)`

Comment: @MattHurst: It is true that it would consider it, but it wouldn't call it unless the argument types actually matched, which seems like the original point anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers are fair solutions. --- @Dave: It doesn't have its own namespace. But it would be possible to add one.
--- @Vaughn: Such using statements seem problematic in my case, because the functions in question are for example operators (`*`,`+`, etc) and templated. Combined with some automatic conversions, the using statements might yield pretty opaque results. ---

So, is there a way to get the *same* behavior for `class X` as for a template class that has a class from `namespace funky` as its argument?

Comment: @MattHurst: I wouldn't expect it to be that bad, but maybe you could give an example.